# building a "scriptable" application

Tags: c#, xml, dynamic

During development of a new application, I was wondering how the most flexible solution of a dynamic, let's say ‘scriptable’, system would look like.

In general, I would need a file in plain text (e.g. TXT or XML) wherein I define a trigger (in my example a hex string) and a corresponding action (open a window, execute a SQL transaction, …). I should be able to add new entries without recompiling the whole application.

As you see, it's not really scriptable this way, but I need a solution to define what happens with which input.

Has anyone got some experience with this?

Comment: How trusted are the scripts? i.e. do you need to isolate them into a lower privileged AppDomain? And do you want to restrict the scripts to a well defined API, or allow them to do basically everything?

Comment: The scripts may be fully trusted. However, I don't want to let they do everything. It would be the best to define an API with the 40, 50 possible functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have only simple program flow you can use [Windows Workflow Foundation Rules Engine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd554919.aspx).

Features

- Inlcuded in dotnet3.0 runtime, no extra costs
- *RuleSetDialog* can be integrated into your code to edit rules including intellisense
- persistable as xml-files.
- ruleengine can evaluate expressions and can perform actions

See also

[A quick and dirty Rules Engine using Windows Workflow Part1](http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10166) and [Part2](http://www.sanderstechnology.com/?p=10491)

I first found this topic when reading the german languaged magazine [dotnetpro 10/2010](http://www.dotnetpro.de/articles/articlearchive1753.aspx) on page 30 "Die Rule-Engine aus .NET ohne Workflow benutzen"

Answer (score 2):

There are various scripting languages you can use inside your .NET application; IronPython being one obvious example, but others are available - javascript for example (talking to your .NET objects; not in a browser). One of these might have some application here?

Comment: well that sounds already quite interesting, but isn't it already 'overdosed'? IronPython is very mighty - in a good way, sure, but maybe there is something easier out there.

Comment: Basically, I just wanna say my c# application "hey, If you receive 0x401234 then do some_function()" - speaking very primtive...

Comment: @Michael - that sounds more like just a key/value list of codes to functions; which you might despatch via reflection, or an enum-switch. Don't over-design; I think using the term "scriptable" is throwing people here...

Answer (score 1):

Well you can embed a .NET language like [IronPython](http://secretgeek.net/host_ironpython.asp) or possibly [Boo](http://boo.codehaus.org/Boo+as+an+embedded+scripting+language)